# How can I properly add material textures to my model?

Tags: textures, materials, godot

This is the first time I'm doing game development and I decided to pick Godot engine.

I downloaded some object on the internet for my initiation learning. There are four files:

1. throp_srub.obj
2. normal.tga
3. diffuse.tga
4. throp_srub.fbx

The fbx didn't appear on the sidebar, so I drag the object mesh and then add spatial material, add diffuse.tga texture to albedo and normal.tga into normal map.

However, it didn't appear as the preview given:

[image]

The object appears like this:

[image]

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Two things i see.
It looks to me like the alpha channel is either not there or not being recognized. Analyse your color Texture.
Second is, that normally the Normal texture should be a blue purple color. This is not the case in your picture. But thats just my experience. If the normals are fine don't worry about the second part.

Comment: More importantly the material needs to be taking shaders that do proper transparency blending.

Comment: how to I add alpha channel in godot ?

Comment: You can add an alpha channel via shading language on godot